# Which of the following statement is correct (concering integral)?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, education

I'm struggling figuring out how to tackle down this exercise.
I don't know how to approach this question. I guess the answer needs to be $I > 0$, because D is alwasy greater or equal then 1. And because inside the integral all the variables are not related to A, so you can see them as constants. So a solution would be $A^2/2 + C$. But I have the feeling that this approach might be wrong. The exercise goes like this.

Let $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |1 \leq x^2 +y^2 \leq3 \}$ if $$I = \iint_D(|x+y|-x-y)dA$$
which of the following is true:
$$I = 0$$
$$I > 0$$
$$I < 0$$

If you know the answer and would like to share it, it would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what a double integral is?

Comment: @Miguel Yes I do, but I'm trying to figure out what exactly the D represents. Are it the bounderies of the integral

Comment: Yes, it is the portion of the plane where the function must be integrated. The differential of area $dA$ can also be written as $dxdy$, so $x, y$ are not constants.

Comment: @Miguel Thank your for clearing that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ \displaystyle I = \iint_D(|x+y|- (x+y)) \ dA$

$D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 |1 \leq x^2 +y^2 \leq3 \}$

$D$ is region between two circles centered at the origin with radius $1$ and $\sqrt3$.

Now in the given region, let's check the sign of the integrand $|x+y| - (x+y)$. Given the absolute term, it is simpler to check the sign in each quadrant separately.

In first quadrant, $x, y \geq 0$ and so integrand is zero and so is the integral.

In second quadrant, $x$ is negative and $y$ is positive. So we divide the region in two -

i) when $y \geq |x|$, the integrand is zero.

ii) when $y \leq |x|$, the integrand is $- 2(x+y)$, which is positive.

So in second quadrant, integral is positive.

Similarly, show that the integral is positive in quadrant $3$ and $4$ as well.

So, $I \gt 0$.

Comment: when $y \gt |x|$ and $x$ is negative, what is $y+x$? positive, right? So $|x+y| - (x+y) = x + y - (x+y) = 0$. Now when $y \lt |x|, x \lt 0$, $x+y$ is negative, right? So $- 2 (x+y)$ will be positive.

Comment: thank you for your answer I get everything up to  the second quandrant, why do you do what you do for i) and ii). (I get the x is negative and y is positive for second quadrant). and shouldn't -2(x+y) be negative cause of the negative sign and my last question for quadrant 1 the integral is zero and for the divided region of quadrant 2 the answer is zero or positive, how do you conclude that the answer is positive

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I really appreciate it, but now I still don't know why you had to split up in i) and ii) and why you can say I > 0. Srry that I don't get i right away, but I'm trying to understand

Comment: one thing at a time - first, you split because you have $|x+y|$ and $y \gt |x|$ example $y = 3, x = - 2$ gives you positive sign of $x+y$ and $y \lt |x|$, example $y = 2, x = - 3$ gives you negative sign of $x+y$. You need to be clear whether $x+y$ is positive or negative before you remove absolute term. You need to know when you remove absolute symbol, whether you will write it as $- (x+y)$ or as $(x+y)$.

Comment: Oh I see know, but this means that both cases can happen right? So the integrand could be 0 or be positive, so why choose positive as conclusion especially when the integrand in the first quadrant is 0

Comment: You are integrating over a simple closed region which is between two circles and is across all four quadrants. The integral over the region is sum of integral over part of the regions in each quadrant. The integral is never negative. It is either positive or zero. So the integral over the entire region will be positive.

Comment: Thank you for spending your time for letting me understand. I really appreciate it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

look at the part of the plain where $x+y=0$ then for $|x+y|=x+y you get 0 for $x+y<0| you get negative integrand.